# Python selenium search for value and select the same not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am beginner to this python3.4 selenium 3. But i am trying to automate some process using chrome driver 54.0version. Code does Search for value(eg.1403) in input field and select the value found in search box is not working in chrome. I have used Keys, ActionChains and execute_script option but non is working.

Input text field html snippet that i am searching a value with "1403"

```
            <input id="ReferenceSearch"
                   data-role="autocomplete"
                   data-place-holder="Enter
                   data-template="reference-search-template"
                   data-min-length="2"
                   data-text-field="Text"
                   style="width: 300px;"
                   required name="ReferenceSearch-Validation"
```

title="Reference is required"/>

After searching, result will be drop-down value which is one of Unordered list value(i.e li element).

  1403 — ODS - Non- Print application  engagement

How can i select searched drop down value using(python selenium webdriver). Below is the code that i am using.

textfield = browser.find_element_by_id('ReferenceSearch')

textfield.send_keys("1403")

textfield.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)

textfield.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('ReferenceSearch')

nextButton.send_keys("1403")

nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)

nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: There is no element with `id` `ReferenceSearch` in your HTML snippet.

Comment: my input field is having that id<input id="ReferenceSearch" data-role="autocomplete" data-place-holder="Enter project/engagement/INC/CRQ/Defect Id...>. When i ran command nextButton.send_keys("1403") then its giving searched value again as some div element which my code is not able to select and enter. the html snippet i have mentioned is the value that came after searching

Comment: Please add your full HTML code, otherwise troubleshooting is guessing and chances are slim you'll get an useful answer.

Comment: Updated with some details, please suggest.

Comment: Now there is even less information. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Apologies that i could not make it present well because of some sensitive business data on html. I have just simplified my question and wants to know that how to control Keyboard Down Arrow and Enter keys in chrome using python selenium web-driver.

Comment: finally i got a solution for this with below code textfield = browser.find_element_by_id('ReferenceSearch')
textfield.send_keys("1403")
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
textfield.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ReferenceSearch_listbox"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
textfield.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
textfield.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: thanks for your time